Macro using ADODB.Connection to pull information from a cell from a closed file only works when the file is open
I am trying to write a program that extracts information from a cell in a closed excel file.
The problem is that the macro doesn't work when the target file is closed but works great when the target file is open.
I am unsure why this is happening.
Any help is appreciated.
Sub ImportDataFromFinishedTravelRequest()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim file As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Dim GetFile As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim unusedRow As Long
    
    'Determines the next empty row in masterfile
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        unusedRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With
    
    'Allows you to select which file to pull information from
    Set file = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With file
        .Title = "Select a File"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        '.InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFile = sItem
    Set file = Nothing

    Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).Clear

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    cn.ConnectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & GetFile & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=No';"

    cn.Open
    
        'Selects which cell in the file to copy
        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    
        rs.ActiveConnection = cn
        rs.Source = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$J14:J14]"
        rs.Open
    
        'Selects which cell in the mastersheet to copy info into
        Sheet1.Range("A" & unusedRow).CopyFromRecordset rs
       
        rs.Close

    cn.Close
    
End Sub


Is the target file on a local drive or network ?

Please, try cn.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=""" & GetFile & """;" & _  "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No"""

@CDP1802 The target file is currently on a local drive but I hope to get it to work with a file on a network

@FaneDuru I tried your way and it worked exactly the same, but I appreciate the help none the less.

The code works for me, do you get an error with closed file ?

@CDP1802 I dont receive an error, the code runs fine but nothing happens if the file is not open

I used an test xlsx file created from a new workbook with one sheet and a value in J14, try that.

Does the workbook in discussion has a sheet named "Sheet1"? Why "J14:J14" and not only "J14"?
